# Having Trouble with SMTP Authentication

Tags: vb.net, smtp, email, smtp-auth

I am trying to make a small email client within a VB.Net program.  The program is suppose to be able to easily email out order PDFs to suppliers once a user has deciding to submit an order.  I am currently using two of my email addresses to test out whether or not I can properly send mail (The From address being my work email which would be using the same server as the app when it is completed).

This is my current setup:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class OrderEmail

    Private _orderNumber As String
    Public ReadOnly Property OrderNumber As String
        Get
            OrderNumber = _orderNumber
        End Get
    End Property

    Private mail As MailMessage

    Public Sub New(ByVal orderNumber As String)
        _orderNumber = orderNumber
        mail = New MailMessage()
        InitializeMessage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeMessage()
        mail.To.Add("MyPersonal@email.com")
        mail.From = New MailAddress("MyWork@Email.com")
        mail.Subject = "Test Email for Order #" & OrderNumber
        mail.Body = "This is a test email"
        mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(INIFuncs.PathPrevDirectory(CurDir) & "PDF\" & OrderNumber & ".pdf"))
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendMessage()
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = "smtpauth.myhost.com"
        smtp.Port = 587
        smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myUsername", "myPassword")
        Try
            smtp.Send(mail)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Quick note or two about the code:

1. I obviously did not include any actual personal data, but I have checked to make sure I have the correct smtp outgoing address, as well as the correct port number.
2. `INIFuncs.GetPathPrevDirectory` is a customer class created to just return the filepath to the directory that the folder the executable file's folder is in.  So if the program is run from `C:/Test/Program/vb.exe` then method will return `C:/Test/`

Now then, when I run the program and attempt to send an email, I am getting the following error:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: SMTP authentication required

When I go through debugging, the `_COMPlusExceptionCode` value is `-532462766`, though I am not sure what to do with knowing this value.

ANy help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Port `587` means `Tls` validation. Set [SmtpClient.EnableSsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.EnableSsl);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)) to `True`, because the default is `False`.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you using a gmail, microsoft (like hotmail) or any other cloud address?

Comment: @Stefan I believe it is a cloud address.  I'd need to double check with the server admin.

Comment: If it's not google or microsoft than usually it's ok.

Comment: @Jimi making that change changed the error message to, `Server does not support secure connections`

Comment: Allright. Then try to set `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False` before setting the new credentials (you have to verify those are correctly written) and `smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network`. If it doesn't work, you might have some stricter server-side protocol in action. Something like Google disallowing "weaker" applications security (meaning the Mail doesn't come from a Google approved app and/or not Android).

Comment: @Jimi making those changes gets me back to the original error message.  I'll have to speak with the network admin and figure out how the outgoing mail server is configured.

Comment: Probably. Are you sure 587 is the correct port? Have you tried port 25? (It shouldn't matter, but give it a go)

Comment: @Jimi I've tried port 25 and it gives me the same error.  I was initially using 587 because that was the port our email clients were using for our outgoing mail.

Comment: It was worth mentioning. If it's a Google account, go to your account settings `Sign-in & Security` and set `Allow less secure apps` to `ON`. If not, you might have something similar in action. The `Mailbox unavailable` part of the message may also indicate that the account is not valid or you are trying to cross-post (relaying) to a different delivery service and it's not supported.